# Android popBackStackImmediate can not remove Glide's SupportRequestManagerFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

```
activity.supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
```

popBackStackImmediate can not remove Glide's SupportRequestManagerFragment, do you know why? and is there any other way I can remove the SupportRequestManagerFragment from fragments stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Glide's Fragment is not on the FragmentManager's operation backstack.

See [code](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/ad33b8d503024c8a3a6a3da60ce28c4d7732ae58/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/manager/RequestManagerRetriever.java#L421).

```
pendingSupportRequestManagerFragments.put(fm, current);
fm.beginTransaction().add(current, FRAGMENT_TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss(); // <-- no addToBackStack() call
```

You probably also shouldn't touch the internals of Glide without good reason, but technically you can call `fragmentManager.getFragments()`, check for null (it can return null), iterate the list, check `if(fragment instanceof SupportRequestManagerFragment)`, and if yes, then remove it with a fragment transaction. But it doesn't seem like a good idea. ^_^

Answer (score 13):

This case  fragment use Activity context instead of fragment context  for Glide.

```
Glide.with(getActivity()).load("url").into(imageView)
```

more details refer [Here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#with%28android.support.v4.app.Fragment%29)

If SupportRequestManagerFragment is getting added to backstack entry of your application fragments stack, then inside fragment call Glide method using base context so its not added and create problem for back press..

```
Glide.with(this.getActivity().getBaseContext()).load("url").into(imageView)
```

Comment: Simpler solution. Thanks